# Deep copy a parent and its children, Shallow copy child.parent references

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a parent and it has a list of children. I have a list of parents too, but no real need to go into that.

I need each child to know its parent, so I set a parent reference property per child. I need to be able to deep copy the parent, which would also deep copy all its children.

I'm using `DataContractSerializer` for my deep copy. My problem is this will take each child's referenced parent and deep copy that too - causing duplicate parents all over; or at least from testing I think that's what happens.

I thought it'd be some simple `DataMember` tag to force a member specific shallow copy, but can't find anything.

Just to add to this, I can't make the parent `IsReference = true` because in my full object structure he can also be a child of a grandparent - in which case I need to deep copy him.

I have tried other approaches such as using indexes rather than class references to get back to the `child.parent` but this raises other fundamental issues which will break the overall design.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can use "IsReference=True" after all. I was concerned that it would break the cases where the class is a child in a list, but in those cases it still does a deep copy. Any other cases where it is just a reference, it simply copies the reference.

Perfect.